# Join and Filter in an arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like this

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Co1 | Te1 | S1 | R1 | Yes |
| 2 | Co1 | Te1 |  | R2 | No |
| 3 | Co1 | Te1 |  | R3 | No |
| 4 | Te2 |  | S2 | R4 | Yes |
| 5 | Te2 |  |  | R5 | No |

I'm using the following drag down formula to join and filter D where A repeats

=IF(E="Yes"; JOIN(CHAR(10);FILTER(D1:D;A1:A=A1;D1:D<>""));"")

The result is the following

row/header|  F
1|  R1
1|   R2
1|   R3
2|  R4
2|   R5

There is a way to achieve the same result with an arrayformula?

Link to the real table (column T)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQpZcLPIlgv4Q62-2Hfg5gv-5AEZz0AQgmC9Pfm3Dxs/edit#gid=306985279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that in a situation like this, an Arrayformula will not make the sheet faster than a dragdown Filter.

That said, here is the traditional way to solve these problems.  Make a new tab.  Place this formula in cell B2.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY({BaseDoc!R7:R&"|"\CHAR(10)&BaseDoc!F7:F};"select MAX(Col2) where Col1<>'|' group by Col2 pivot Col1");;9^9)));"|";0)))
```

Those results should give you the table you need.  If desired, you can do an Arrayformula(Vlookup( into the range to report back to your original tab.